# Regex: Trimming URL to Root

Tags: regex

Out of all the threads I've seen, I haven't been able to find a clear regex pattern that will accurately trim any given URL to it's domain root. A lot of the solutions were avoiding regex by using some PHP method or something but I'm in Python and want to use a simple regex expression.

Here's what I have:

```
http://([^/]+).*
```

However, this doesn't account for exceptions like domains that have:

```
'http' or 'http://www.'
```

Does anyone have a regex expression that handles all these crazy excepts? Thanks so much!

Edit: Here are some sample inputs:

```
http://toronto.kijiji.ca/f-cars-vehicles-cars-trucks-W0QQCatIdZ174
http://wwwa.autotrader.ca/cars/on/toronto/
http://toronto.en.craigslist.ca/cta/
http://www.auto123.com/en/used-cars/classified/ontario/toronto?city=toronto
https://www.123-reg.co.uk/email-hosting/
```

Sample outputs:

```
kijiji.ca
autotrader.ca
craigslist.ca
auto123.com
123-reg.co.uk
```

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint you, but there is no "prefect" regex for URL's; there will always be some exceptions you can't account for.

Comment: Just for clarity, can you please provide some sample input/output

Comment: Sample output would help too.

Comment: What do you want the output to be? "http" or "http:" or "http://"?

Comment: Added sample outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done with a "simple regex." If all extensions were single-part, yes (see below), but there is no way to distinguish by pattern with second-level domains. For example, `abc.co.uk` has the same pattern as `abc.uk.co`, but in the first case you'd want to return `abc.co.uk` and in the second you'd want `uk.co`. Your function needs some awareness of valid TLDs and second-level domains.

```
https?:\/\/(?:.*\.)*(.+\..+?)\/
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds about right when I was thinking about this too. So if I detected if the domain extension has a period in it, how would the regex go for that?

Answer (score 1):

I have this one (I'm not really sure where I got it from):

```
[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})
```

The problem with it is the initial www. especially, because there might be other subdomains, like the ones you have in your examples.

Maybe you can do a string replace to remove the extra www. in case the resulting strings have it.

You can see it working [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/4vk).

Also, I think you should consider things like:

```
http
https
www.domain.co.uk
photos.domain.co.uk
```